# Do quantum states with a single parameter give any theoretical or experimental advantage compared to multi-parameter ones?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, quantum-operation, experimental-realization, state-tomography

If a quantum state is a single parameter two-qubit mixed entangled state then is there any theoretical or experimental advantage compared to a multi-parameter state?

suppose, we take a single parameter state

$\rho_1= \lambda|\phi^+\rangle\langle\phi^+|+(1-\lambda)|10\rangle\langle10|$

where $|\phi^+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$
and
$0\leq\lambda\leq1$.

and a multi parameter state
$\rho_2= \lambda|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|+(1-\lambda)|10\rangle\langle10|$,

where $|\phi\rangle=a|00\rangle+b|11\rangle$, $a^2+b^2=1$
and
$0\leq\lambda\leq1$.

Is there any advantage of $\rho_1$ compared to $\rho_2$?

Lets, someone wants to do an information processing task or any kind of communication task using either $\rho_1$ or $\rho_2$ (both have the same amount of entanglement). I want to ask here, is there any advantage of a single parameter state during the preparation of these states in the lab?
Or, in the state estimation method/Tomography process, do we need a lesser number of operations compared to multi-parameter states?

Comment: Why do you mean by "advantage"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about advantage in terms of, ease of handling/preparing or tomography, perhaps.

Comment: Advantage in the sense, I mean is it easy to handle/ during the preparation/adaptive state estimation or any kind of experimental or theoretical advantage?

Comment: define "easy to handle". The parameters are the way you describe the state, they don't generally have a direct physical meaning. Though in an quantum estimation context their number certainly matters because then parameters also somehow codify your state of knowledge of the system, or at least what you are trying to estimate about it.

Comment: Easy to handle means, suppose someone want to perform a information processing or any communication task in lab then is there any advantage ?